# Laravel 8 Send Mail by Gmail get stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)

Tags: laravel, gmail, laravel-8, sendmail

I have tried send mail by

MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AND

MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

And I allow the option "less secure app"

But always get this notification:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)

My Laravel Version is
Laravel Framework 8.34.0
and using ubuntu 18.04

How can I fix this problem
Thanks everyone

Comment: Have you tried with smtp.googlemail.com as mail host?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue on my *local setup of a Laravel 8 project*. Much of the search I did did not solve the issue and as a last resort I tried sending the mail with a VPN and it worked.

**So try with a VPN**. I am using Betternet